# Load form in WPF with different mode

Tags: wpf, mode

I have the WPF application. I am trying to open the User Entry form as per Mode(Edit,Update,Delete). so somewhere I have to check the for this mode. and somehow load the for as per mode. Where have to define mode, where have to check mode, and how to navigate respected form ? There is OnLoaded event in code behind. I am new in WPF so please help me for the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should be a good way to let `Window` know what mode it should be in:

### Window:

```
public enum Mode
{
    Edit, Update, Delete
}

public class MyWindow : Window
{
    public Mode Mode { get; set; }

    public MyWindow()
    {
        InititalizeComponent();

        Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MyWindow_Loaded);
    }

    void MyWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (Mode)
        {
            case Mode.Edit:
                // Changes needed in UI for Edit Mode
                break;
            case Mode.Update:
                // Changes needed in UI for Update Mode
                break;
            case Mode.Delete:
                // Changes needed in UI for Delete Mode
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

### Usage:

```
public void MyWindowTest()
{
    MyWindow window = new MyWindow();
    window.Mode = Mode.Edit;
    window.Show();
}
```

Comment: Yes same like that. but can we navigate to particular form from usercontrol in wpf with specific mode? I have used usercontrol to decide for mode. what it needs.

Comment: Are you using `Frame/Page/Navigation` in WPF? If not what do you mean by navigating? And you should look into it.